# Is the intersection of a power set always empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I make this question because of a book exercise, in which I have to use the intersection of a power set. That is, given a non-empty set $A$, I need to use $\bigcap_{X \in \mathcal{P}(A)}X$, but knowing that the definition of intersection of sets is $\bigcap_{X \in \mathcal{A}}X = \{x | x \in X \text{ for all } X \in \mathcal{A} \}$ and that a power set always contains the empty set, the set in the definition will always be empty because there is no $x$ which belongs to the empty set. Is that deduction correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Yes, your deduction is correct. Given a non-empty set $A$, the power set $P(A)$ contains all possible subsets of $A$, including the empty set. When you take the intersection of all the sets in the power set, $⋂X∈P(A)X$, you are essentially trying to find the elements that are common to all the subsets.

Answer (score 3):

This is true
even if the null set is excluded from the power set
as long as the base set has
at least two elements
because we can always choose
two distinct elements
as the sets to be
intersected.